# Generation of PDF from Google Form using Doc template using Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am using this script to create PDF from Google from using template in Google Docs.

The script I am using is as below:

```
function afterFormSubmit(e) {
    const info = e.namedValues;
    const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
    const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
    const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2")
    ws.getRange(entryRow, 63).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());
    ws.getRange(entryRow, 64).setValue(pdfFile.getName());
    
    sendEmail(e.namedValues ['Email address'][0],pdfFile);
}


function sendEmail(email,pdfFile){
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Daily Transation Summary Report", "Please find the attached DTR", {
    attachments : [pdfFile],
    name: 'My Company'
});

}  
  
function createPDF(info) {
  
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1ebglel6vwMGXByeG4wHBBvJu9u0zJeMJ");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1ebglel6vwMGXByeG4wHBBvJu9u0zJeMJ");
  const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1kyFimRMdHQZV85F5P6JyCHv1DQ3KJFv1hx5o7lIcNZo");
  
  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{Name of Person}", info['Name of Person'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Date of Report}", info['Date of Report'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Name of Outlet}", info['Name of Outlet'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Opening Petty Cash Balance}", info['Opening Petty Cash Balance'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Petty Cash Received}", info['Total Petty Cash Received'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Closing Petty Cash Balance}", info['Closing Petty Cash Balance'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Petty Cash Paid}", info['Total Petty Cash Paid'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Available Float Cash Balance}", info['Available Float Cash Balance'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Milk For Outlet}", info['Milk For Outlet'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Staff Milk/Toast etc.}", info['Staff Milk/Toast etc.'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Petrol Expenses}", info['Petrol Expenses'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Water Tank Charges}", info['Water Tank Charges'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Repair And Maintenance}", info['Repair And Maintenance'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Freight Paid}", info['Freight Paid'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Purchase of Soya Chaap}", info['Purchase of Soya Chaap'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Purchase of Rumali Roti}", info['Purchase of Rumali Roti'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Purchase of Egg Tray}", info['Purchase of Egg Tray'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Other Expenses}", info['Other Expenses'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Tip Amount (PAYTM & CARD)}", info['Total Tip Amount (PAYTM & CARD)'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Cash Sales - Outlet}", info['Cash Sales - Outlet'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Cash Sales - KCCO App}", info['Cash Sales - KCCO App'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Card Sales}", info['Card Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Credit (Udhar) Sales}", info['Credit (Udhar) Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Paytm Sales}", info['Paytm Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{KCCO App Sales Razor Pay}", info['KCCO App Sales Razor Pay'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Swiggy Sales}", info['Swiggy Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Zomato Sales}", info['Zomato Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Dunzo Sales}", info['Dunzo Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Zomato Gold Sales}", info['Zomato Gold Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Dine Out Sales}", info['Dine Out Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Cancelled Bill Amount}", info['Total Cancelled Bill Amount'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Sales of the Day (Total of Above)}", info['Total Sales of the Day (Total of Above)'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Sales of the Day (As Per PetPooja)}", info['Total Sales of the Day (As Per PetPooja)'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Old Due Receipts  - Cash}", info['Old Due Receipts  - Cash'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Old Due Receipts - Other Modes}", info['Old Due Receipts - Other Modes'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Tip Receipts - Card}", info['Tip Receipts - Card'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Tip Receipts - Paytm}", info['Tip Receipts - Paytm'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 2000}", info['Currency Note of INR 2000'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 500}", info['Currency Note of INR 500'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{ Currency Note of INR 200}", info[' Currency Note of INR 200'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 100}", info['Currency Note of INR 100'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 50}", info['Currency Note of INR 50'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 20}", info['Currency Note of INR 20'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 10}", info['Currency Note of INR 10'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Other Currency Note/Coins}", info['Other Currency Note/Coins'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Available Cash to Handover}", info['Total Available Cash to Handover'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Credit Approval By// Bill No// Total Amount of Credit", info['S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Credit Approval By// Bill No// Total Amount of Credit'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total No. of Bills of Credit Recovery}", info['Total No. of Bills of Credit Recovery'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Mode of Payment// Bill No// Total Amount Received}", info['S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Mode of Payment// Bill No// Total Amount Received'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total No. of Complementary Bills  During the Day}", info['Total No. of Complementary Bills  During the Day'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No//Reason// Bill No//Amount Settled}", info['S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No//Reason// Bill No//Amount Settled'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total No. of Cancelled Bills During the Day}", info['Total No. of Cancelled Bills During the Day'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Bill No// Bill Amount}", info['S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Bill No// Bill Amount'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{S.No.// Bill No// Mode of Payment//Tip Amount Received}", info['S.No.// Bill No// Mode of Payment//Tip Amount Received'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{No. of Cylinders Received at Outlet}", info['No. of Cylinders Received at Outlet'][0]); 
  
  openDoc.saveAndClose();
  
  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Name of Outlet'][0]+ " " + info['Date of Report'][0]);
  tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);
    
  return pdfFile;
  
}
```

This script is not generating PDF as well PDF is not being Mailed.

The link of Spreadsheet is as below

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m6Aca0TcLf5UZ7P9CvAdQDokoazQljsqDT6CGh0K3j4/edit?usp=sharing

Please guide.

Comment: From `This script is not generating PDF as well PDF is not being Mailed.`, I thought that an error might have already occurred at `const pdfFile = createPDF(info);`. So, if an error occurs, can you show the error message?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined
    at afterFormSubmit(Code:2:20)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined at afterFormSubmit(Code:2:20)`, when you had directly run the function of `afterFormSubmit` at the script editor, such error occurs. Because the event object of `e` is not given. When I saw your script, I thought that you have wanted to create your script to execute the script by the form submission trigger. How about this?

Comment: Yes.. I want to create PDF when user submit the form. For this i have added trigger on form Submit also.

Comment: it shows this error while submitting form...TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at createPDF(Code:39:64)
    at afterFormSubmit(Code:3:21)

Comment: About `While I execute Email Script... it shows this error...` I assume you mean the function `sendEmail`, and you are not executing it manually from the editor, right? (otherwise, `email` and `pdfFile` are undefined). About `it shows this error while submitting form...TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`, this means some of the properties from `info` (e.g. `Name of Person`) don't actually exist. In order to test this, consider adding `Logger.log(info)` after `const info = e.namedValues;` in order to check what properties does it include.

Comment: didn't work anything... While i am using google form and submitted the form it shows below error................it shows this error while submitting form...TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at createPDF(Code:39:64) at afterFormSubmit(Code:3:21)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, it seems that the error message was changed. Can I ask you about the difference between `TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined at afterFormSubmit(Code:2:20)` and `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at createPDF(Code:39:64)`? And, in your script, can you provide the sample value of `e` for replicating your issue?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined at afterFormSubmit(Code:2:20) - This error was coming while I run CreatePDF script individually....   and TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at createPDF(Code:39:64)... this error comes when I submit google form ...

Comment: Did you log info, as I mentioned in my previous comment? Please consider adding `Logger.log(info)`, and then check the `Executions` tab in your script to see what's being logged, and copy the logged data in here. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#use_the_apps_script_execution_log for more information.

Comment: I have made some changes in the script now... and its working...Thanks everyone for help